# Can't reduce bootcamp partition size in El Capitan

Tags: macos, partition

I have a 512GB hard disk using the latest macbook pro running El Capitan. When bootcamp partition was created it was allocated 350GB. Now I want to bring that down to 100GB since the windows partition is hardly ever used. Bootcamp is running Windows 10 Pro.

[image][image]

Disk Utility won't let me reduce the bootcamp partition. The slider let's you shrink macs partition but not bootcamps!

[image]

Disk Manager from windows 10 looks like the below: (sorry about the compression!):

[image]

I've also tried tool named iPartition but it report "destructive process for the selected changes".

Here's how my partition table looks (note I don't understand the output myself, but hope someone here can help):

```
diskutil list
sudo gpt -r -vvv show -l /dev/disk0
sudo fdisk /dev/disk0




gpt show: /dev/disk0: mediasize=500277790720; sectorsize=512; blocks=977105060
gpt show: /dev/disk0: PMBR at sector 0
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Pri GPT at sector 1
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B, start=40, size=409600
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=409640, size=291724536
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC, start=292134176, size=1269536
gpt show: /dev/disk0: GPT partition: type=EBD0A0A2-B9E5-4433-87C0-68B6B72699C7, start=293404672, size=683700224
gpt show: /dev/disk0: Sec GPT at sector 977105059
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         PMBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - "EFI System Partition"
     409640  291724536      2  GPT part - "OSX"
  292134176    1269536      3  GPT part - "Recovery HD"
  293403712        960
  293404672  683700224      4  GPT part - "BOOTCAMP"
  977104896        131
  977105027         32         Sec GPT table
  977105059          1         Sec GPT header
```

**Can anyone help guide me reducing bootcamp partition?**

Comment: When you are running Disk Management under Windows, how much can you shrink the Boot Camp partition? At this point, I am not asking you to actually shrink the partition. I just want know how much it can be shrunk. Just to let you know, it would probably be easier to delete the Boot Camp partition and reinstall Windows in a new 100 GB partition.

Comment: From the menu bar, select "About this Mac". Edit your question and post the  year and screen size of your Mac. Also, which version  of Windows are you running?.

Comment: @DavidAnderson updated the question

Comment: You probably will not be able to shrink the Boot Camp partition down to 100 GB. Currently  the smallest is ~185 GB. You might be able to free more space if you defragment the Boot Camp volume. Unless you get the size down to less than 175 GB, it would be difficult to move the Boot Camp partition. You need to move the Boot Camp partition before you can expand the OS X partition  to fill the free space. Another possibility would be to purchase a product to help shrink/move the BootCamp partition. [Winclone](http://twocanoes.com/products/mac/winclone) is such a product.